# If the area of an Isosceles triangle $ABC $ is $9*\sqrt{3}$ ; What is the area of Circumcircle of this Triangle?

Tags: geometry

> If the area of an Isosceles triangle $ABC $  is $9*\sqrt{3}$ ; What is the area of Circumcircle of this  Triangle ?

I tried to use herone formula but ; i got stuck

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is your work on the subject ?

Comment: @JeanMarie  since  the area of  triangle  is given ; i tried to use herone formula ; but got stuck

Comment: This question is unanswerable, there are infinitely many possible values of area. You either need to put some constraint on $ABC$ or ask for the minimum possible value of the area (which is achieved when $ABC$ is equilateral).

Comment: @achille hui  it seems that the question need some additional information;  thank you very much

Comment: It is easy to answer if the question asks about an equilateral triangle - are you sure this isn't the case? (in which case, the answer is $12\pi$).

Answer (score 3):

The area cannot have a fixed value ; in particular, it can be arbitrarily large.

Proof: Let $BC$ be the base of this isosceles triangle. It suffices to see that one can have an arbitrarily large chord, because the diameter of a circle is at least as large as any of its chords. For any arbitrarily large value of  $AB$, it suffices to take a height equal to $9 \sqrt{3}/(2 AB)$ to meet the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

$$9\sqrt3=(2R\sin A)^2\cdot2R\sin(\pi-2A)/4R=4R^2\sin^3A\cos A$$

where $0<A<90^\circ$

Now area of circum circle $=\pi R^2$ which is clearly arbitrary.